# Apache shared content with samba

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, storage, samba

I want to have two webservers with shared storage.

Currently my setup is the following:
(Router)<->(Firewall + Load Balancer(pfSense)) <-> Webserver{1,2}, Storage

I only work with centOS on webserver and storage.
All webservers and the storage server are containers in my proxmox cluster.

After installing samba on my storage server, I mounted that to my webservers.
Now, I done an clean install of typo3.

Problem: The whole page are very slow (Loads in 8-10 seconds).

To check, what the problem is, I unmounted the samba share and copied the files manually into that directory.
Now it works like a charm, load times from 1 to 3 seconds.

What is my problem? Should a samba share works for that? Or maybe are my disks or CPU too slow?

Any idea how to check what goes wrong? Or is there any other way without using samba?

Comment: I would double check name resolution. On webserver please check with nmblookup if storage server name resolution works. Just a guess.

Comment: @473183469 I use my internal ip: 192.168.1.xx. So I use no names curretly... any other idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend looking to NFS for storage. This will work faster. Samba is more focused on providing access to files for users.

Also check the DNS settings on all hosts. It's samba specific. Clients try to resolve servers name even if you connect by ip. Server is represented in the smb protocol according `smb.conf` configured name.